# function pointer error

Tags: c++, function, pointers

Can anybody help me with this simple code??

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void testFunction(){
    cout<<"This is the test function 0"<<endl;
}

void testFunction1(){
    cout<<"This is the test function 1"<<endl;
}

void testFunction2(){
    cout<<"This is the test function 2"<<endl;
}

void (*fp[])()={testFunction,testFunction1,testFunction2};

int main(){

    //fp=testFunction;
    (*fp[testFunction1])();
    //cout<<"Addrees of the function pointer is:"<<*fp;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error: invalid types `void (*[3])()[void ()()]' for array subscript|
```

Comment: That is really evil stuff, by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to use a function pointer as an array index. That won't fly, array indices must be integer.

To call through a function pointer, just call:

```
(*fp[1])();
```

or the (even shorter!)

```
fp[1]();
```

will work.

Comment: Thanks ...i don't know how i missed that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to write:

```
(*fp[1])();
```

That is, you index the array with an int rather than the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

Your indexing the array `fp` of functions with a function pointer, try something like:

```
(*fp[some_index])();
```

instead